# Noise generator with LM318

Tags: diodes, noise, zener, operational-amplifier

[image: Noise generator]

I want to build a noise generator from a Zener diode. I designed the above circuit. The noisy voltage from the diode is filtered via a high-pass filter and input into a 92x gain non-inverting amplifier. (I replaced the 10k resistor by a 100k to increase the gain). The power sources are from 2 AC-DC adaptors at 11.6V. The op-amp is an LM318P and the diode is a 1N755A

Although I am using a diode with Vz=7.5V, the voltage actually drops by 9V. The current through the 100 ohm resistor is 16mA, well below the max current of the diode. At last I filter the output to limit the band to below the Nyquist frequency of a cheap PC-based oscilloscope and limit its max voltage to protect it. Results are shown below.

My problem is that the output signal exhibits a periodic signal of about 3kHz:

[image: Noise output with periodic component]

What is wrong? Hints would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried another zener? This is kind of an off-label application. If you replace the 100pF with 10nF do you still see the 3kHz?

Comment: Thx. Will try your suggestions tmr. I will let you know.

Comment: I would try other diodes of the same voltage, but also 5 volt zener diodes. There is a possibility your noise source may have a resonate frequency based on temperature and your load capacitance.

Comment: Your gain is only 9X. Nine.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa7t5D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your oscillation could be

1) thermal oscillation inside the Opamp, as the output current causes changes in the silicon heating, and the input bipolar diffpair becomes imbalanced; however the delta_V_out is 1 volt, so I doubt thermal feedback is the cause

2) how about 0.1 volts of I*R drop inside the battery, as the 10 or 20mA thru the Zener starts up, and the opamp amplifies that 0.1 volts by 10X to produce the 1 volt output? Yes. An internal resistance of 10 ohms or 5 ohms will cause this.